# Remove the election notification after casting vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

`Please participate in the Programmers 2012 community moderator election`

I have already cast my vote in the moderator election, why am I still seeing this?

I think it should be removed after casting my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is a system message and, as such, cannot be dismissed by individual users.

This has been brought up before [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/allow-us-an-exit-hatch-to-dismiss-the-system-message-notification-bar) and has always been declined.

Answer (score 4):

I voted the first day but it was handy for me to have there because I went back and changed my vote around a couple of times. May as well leave it up.

Comment: I agree, I used it to change my vote too. I know you can access it by `programmers.stackexchange.com/election`, but the banner is easier